# How to get a Vec<T> from a yew::UseStateHandle<Vec<T>>

Tags: rust, yew

```rust
use gloo::console::log;
use std::ops::Deref;
use web_sys::FileList;
use yew::prelude::*;


let filelist: UseStateHandle<Vec<FileList>> = use_state(|| vec![]);

Callback::from(move |event: DragEvent| {
    event.prevent_default();
    let files = event.data_transfer().unwrap().files();
    // log!(files);
    let cloned_filelist = filelist.clone();
    let mut filelistvalue = *cloned_filelist.deref().clone();
    // filelist_vec.push(files);   
})
```

`*cloned_filelist.deref().clone()` gives a slice `[FileList]` instead of `Vec<FileList>`

How can I use get a `Vec` from `use_state` and mutate it?

Comment: You don't need to import [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) (you seldomly need to for things in `std::ops` unless you're implementing them), just use `*cloned_filelist`.

Comment: This seems only tangentially a duplicate question -- the central fact is that UseSateHandler can be deref into a slice and then the other answer applies in this case, but that is not obvious to a new Yew person like myself, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_vec` for that:

```rust
use yew::prelude::*;
#[derive(Clone)]
struct FileList;
#[function_component(Main)]
fn main() -> Html {
    let filelist: UseStateHandle<Vec<FileList>> = use_state(|| vec![]);
    let files = FileList;
    let mut cloned: Vec<_> = filelist.to_vec();
    cloned.push(files);
    filelist.set(cloned);
    todo!()
}
```